# Manage a wide array of devices centrally, from one console

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm looking for an application that will help me manage a wide array of mobile (potentially desktops, if possible) devices centrally, from one console. It can be a paid service/product.

This is long, so **there's a TL;DR at the bottom** that I've done my best to make concise but informative. You can get the entire scoop only from the TL;DR.

Thank you for any suggestions and your time.

---

## Background & Features Desired

### MDM

In searching for a solution, it seems most Mobile Device Management (MDM) solutions are focused on technical management the devices for the purpose of keeping them updated, secure and in compliance with company and industry regulations. It makes sense why this is the case, and it's not surprising.

Being able to manage the devices' OS updates and other technical aspects is important and something that I am looking for, but the main goal is to actually use the devices from a unified console. Ideally, this would include being able to actually use the apps on the phones themselves.

So, when I say "manage," as I did in the first paragraph, it's the ability to *use* features and functionality of the devices that are enrolled in the software/service that's most important to me.

### Where I'm coming from

I'm a sales rep for one company and I also work on several side projects. I have one work mobile, one personal mobile, one project mobile a few home-office VOIP lines and potentially more.

VOIP doesn't need to be addressed currently--MDM seems complicated enough to implement on its own--but if there is something that can integrate all of these diverse channels, that would be ideal.

I've mentioned above that I'm looking primarily for MDM as a communications tool than as a technical tool. As a sales rep and in trying to build up my side projects, the main goal is unified communications and customer relationship management from each device, centrally, rather than purely technical management.

#### Important Point

I'd be owning all the devices, the only one using them and communicating from them. This could be important if you consider that all the devices would be located within arm's length of the computer I'm working on. I'm not sure if that matters for some software, but there you go.

### G Suite

Google's G Suite is currently part of my software stack. They have device management capabilities that are good for my requirements; G Suite's MDM represents about the most I'd need on the technical/provisioning side of the MDM equation, although I've only used Android devices with it.

An example of what I'm looking for would be a GUI like G Suite's MDM, but with each device having a section into which you can drill down and control the device: send text messages, emails and even use apps.

A good software solution for this need would almost be an integration with G Suite and aspects of Google Voice, like Google Voice's ability to send SMS messages from the phones.

### Devices & Communications managed

#### iOS/iPad

- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPad Pro
- iPad Air

#### Android

- Moto E
- Motorola Droid Turbo

#### Other

- Desktop device management of Windows and Mac devices would be a plus, but not sure how much complexity this introduces.
- Great if there would be some way to integrate Vonage Business, Kixie Sales and any other VOIP-based channels into all this.

---

## TL;DR

#### Looking for

- Way to manage a wide array of devices (mixed OS environment incl. iOS, Android, Windows 7 & 10 and macOS, centrally, from one console.
- Main goal is communication and being able to use the phones remotely, rather than only provisioning and technical management (though this capability is welcome).
- Can be a paid service.
- Probably would have to be a web app. But a desktop client or application would be great. Apps for iOS and Android would be great too.

### Close to what I'm looking for:

- If you could merge & integrate G Suite's MDM and Google Voice's feature set into one console.
- Ringcentral's Unified Communication as a Service (incl. Business SMS)